# Only discrete topology gives trivial topos?

Tags: sheaf-theory, topos-theory, grothendieck-topology

Given a Grothendieck site $\mathsf{(C,\tau)}$, if the associated Grothendieck topos $\mathsf{Shv(C,\tau)}$ is trivial, i.e. $\mathsf{Shv(C,\tau)}$ consists of the terminal sheaf $*$ only, can we conclude that the topology $\tau$ is the discrete topology—the finest topology on $\mathsf{C}$, namely for every object $X$, every sieve is a covering sieve?

Note that the converse is true by applying the sheaf condition to the empty covering sieve of $X$. And to show the above to be true (if it is), one only needs to show the empty sieve of $X$ is a covering for every $X$.

Even more generally, does a strict refinement of a topology give strictly less sheaves?

Remark: It's not hard to show on the other extreme that, every presheaf on $\mathsf{C}$ is a sheaf iff the topology $\tau$ is the chaotic topology (or indiscrete topology), i.e. the only covering sieve of any $X$ is $h_X$.

Comment: The correspondence between Grothendieck topology and localization of a topos is bijective (see SGA 4), so if two topologies have the same sheaves then they are equal.

Comment: Could you be more precise?

Comment: I'm affraid I don't see how to be more precise than "If two topologies have the same sheaves then they are equal". Are you asking for a reference ?

Comment: Right, e.g. where in SGA4; other reference would be also OK.

Comment: Just to record that I find a reference here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00ZP and so indeed a strict refinement of a topology gives strictly less sheaves.